# SQL Need help to assign unique number or a sequence number based of Date oldest to newest and based on product name and price

Tags: sql, teradata

[image]

Helo,

I would like to assign unique sequence number based on Unit_cost as mentioned in the picture. But the catch here is it should assigned based on date as well. Basically want to look at price change at during different posting date. Whenever price changes need to assign the next number.

Attached is the type of output in column seq num which i am looking at.

Please help

Comment: Is this you final result or do you want to add additional processing?

Comment: Your question suggests that the data is ordered.  However, there is no column that fully orders the rows.  How do you know the ordering?  Does `posting_date` also have a time component?

Answer (score 0):

This is a *gaps & islands" problem:

```
select ...
   sum(flag)
   over (partition by item_description ?
         order by posting_date
         rows unbounded preceding) 
from
 (
    select ...
       case when unit_cost 
           = lag(unit_cost) 
             over (partition by item_description ?
                   order by posting_date)
            then 0
            else 1 -- price changed
       end as flag
    from tab
 ) as dt
```

Caution:
This needs a unique (= repeatable) ORDER BY, your example data doesn't show that.